# How to use factorial operator in python? ex:- 4! expected output is 24

Tags: python, math, operators, python-3.7

Why  the output of the following :

4!  is error

**( ! is mathematical operator i.e, Factorial )**

> File "", line 2
> 4!
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax*

But, the expected output is (Mathematically)

```
4! = 4 * 3 * 2 = 24
```

hence output: 24 (Mathematically)

But, In python, its output is:  Error(why ?)

Comment: Look at `from math import factorial` method for your purpose.

Comment: Because `!` is not a valid operator in python. .. and 3^4 is not 3 to the power of 4.

Comment: See [mapping-operators-to-functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions) for some operators and their function counterparts that do exist.

Comment: If you want a slowish alternative: `def factorial(i): return 1 if i == 1 else i * fact(i-1)` - and do not feed it negative numbers (or check for them and quit).

Answer (score 1):

The notation that is common used in mathematics does not necessarily translate to Python. As you can see by the `SyntaxError`, the operator `!` is not valid. You can see the full list of operators in [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/operator.html). For the purpose of calculating a factorial you can use different modules such as `math`, `numpy` or `scipy`:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.math.factorial(4))

import scipy
print(scipy.math.factorial(4))

import math
print(math.factorial(4))
```

The three of them yielding the result of 24